# Портмоне чи гаманець? Яка між ними різниця? У якому випадку яке слово краще вживати?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Обидва слова є запозиченими, це синоніми з одним і тим же значенням "носити гроші" "для грошей". Але чомусь здавалося завжди, що *"портмоне"* це чоловічий предмет, а *"гаманець"* - жіночий, і що вони навіть зовні відрізняються...

На просторах інтернету не знайшла авторитетного джерела яке б розвіяло сумніви. 
Знайшла [такий опис](http://skrunia.kiev.ua/articles/?id=138) цих предметів - але ж я розумію що це просто інтернет магазин.

Answer (score 3):

У [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=17587&page=591) читаємо:

> **ГАМАНЕ́ЦЬ**, нця́, ч. Зменш. до ***гама́н***.
>
> *ГАМА́Н*, а́, ч.1. Шкіряна сумочка для грошей. 3. Те саме, що ***бума́жник***.
>
> *БУМА́ЖНИК*, а, ч., заст. Кишеньковий портфельчик для паперових грошей і документів.

Щодо визначення іншого слова, то стаття є, але без вказування на особливості, що можуть відрізняти "гаманець" від "портмоне".

> **ПОРТМОНЕ́**, невідм., сер. *Гаманець для грошей.*

У [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/36/53407/246315.html) читаємо, що:

> **Портмоне** - маленький гаманець.

Щодо "***гаманець***", то подають *те ж визначення, що і СУМ-20*.

Однак на сайті [Моя освіта](http://moyaosvita.com.ua/krasa-moda/chim-vidriznyayetsya-portmone-vid-gamancya/) знайшла таке пояснення:

> **Портмоне** – невеликий гаманець з кількома відділеннями, призначений і для грошей, і для документів.
>
> **Гаманець** – плоска маленька сумочка, зазвичай зі шкіри або тканини, яка використовується для носіння та зберігання готівки.
>
> **Портмоне** бувають як чоловічими, так і жіночими, **гаманець** – виключно дамський аксесуар.
>
> **Гаманець** зазвичай має загальну застібку, а **портмоне** – ні.
>
> **Портмоне**, в порівнянні з гаманцем, відрізняється строгістю квітів та оздоблення. **Портмоне** зазвичай шкіряне, **гаманець** може бути практично з будь-якого матеріалу.

Comment: Наведена стаття з сайту «Моя освіта» — це переклад [російської статті](https://thedifference.ru/chem-otlichaetsya-portmone-ot-koshelka/) з сайту TheDifference.ru.

Comment: Висновок «гаманець – виключно дамський аксесуар» викликає великі сумніви.

Answer (score -1):

Давайте розглянемо різницю між портмоне та гаманцем на основі деяких джерел. Ось що пише цей [вебсайт](https://embargo.ua/ua/articles/drugoe/kak-vybrat-modnye-muzhskie-koshelki/):

> Між портмоне і гаманцем існує деяка різниця. **У перших є більше
>   кишень.** Але якщо в них немає необхідності, то придбання великого
>   портмоне не виправдовує себе. Красивий і модний чоловічий гаманець, в
>   якому стануть просто акуратно лежатимуть гроші, набагато переважніше.

[Тут](http://yakszrobiti.ru/insha/krasa-moda-stil/29500-chim-vidriznjaetsja-portmone-vid-gamancja.html#i-1) вже бачемо більше інформації:

> **Портмоне** - Невеликий гаманець з кількома відділеннями, призначений і для грошей, і для документів.
>
> **Гаманець** - Плоска маленька сумочка, зазвичай зі шкіри або тканини, яка використовується для носіння та зберігання готівки.
>
> **Сучасний гаманець - переважно дамський аксесуар.** Зазвичай його довжина
>   становить 17-20 см, а ширина - 8-10 см, що дозволяє складати в
>   гаманець купюри, причому навіть найбільшого гідності, в розгорнутому
>   вигляді. Таку річ через її габаритів вельми незручно носити в кишені,
>   а ось в дамській сумочці вона розташовується просто відмінно.
>   **Компактне портмоне ж якраз чудово поміщається в кишеню брюк або
>   сорочки, що дуже зручно для чоловіків,** які вважають за краще, щоб руки
>   у них були завжди вільні. **За розмірами портмоне менше гаманця**, тому
>   купюри в ньому зазвичай складаються навпіл: цілком вони просто не
>   поміщаються.

Тобто, виходить, що ви праві - *"портмоне" це чоловічий предмет, а "гаманець" - жіночий*. Дивимося дальше:

> **У гаманці зазвичай є і відділення з блискавкою, і потаємні кишеньки, і
>   місця для візиток, дисконтних і кредитних карток.** У всіх гаманцях в
>   обов'язковому порядку присутній відділення для дрібниці, а от у
>   портмоне його може і не бути. Причому якщо таке відділення все ж
>   наявне в портмоне, то закриватися воно буде виключно на застібку у
>   вигляді кнопки, а ось в гаманці дрібниця може ховатися як за кнопкою,
>   так і за засувкою. **Портмоне - настільки аскетичний аксесуар, що він
>   частенько обходиться і без загальної застібки**. А
>   ось у гаманця зовні, як правило, є або хлястик з липучкою, або
>   застібка-кнопка.
>
> **Портмоне, в порівнянні з гаманцем, відрізняється строгістю кольорів та
>   оздоблення.**
>
> **Портмоне зазвичай шкіряне, гаманець може бути практично з будь-якого
>   матеріалу.**

На рахунок того, який же з цих аксесуарів чоловічий, а який жіночий. Наскільки я зрозумів портмоне для чоловіків, а гаманці для жінок. Однак, завжди є виключення - все ж таки існують чоловічі гаманці та [жіночі портмоне](http://www.mi-lady.com/portmone-gamanetsy-kupyurnik-v-yaka-rznitsya-mzh-tsimi-galantereynimi-virobami-dlya-tcholovkv.html):

> Всі звикли вважати портмоне суто чоловічим аксесуаром, проте виробники
>   даних товарів розробили витончені портмоне для жінок. Вони
>   відрізняються яскравістю, декором, формою.

Різниця також і полягає в тому, що гаманець призначений і для зберігання монет, а от портмане лише для паперових грошей (в основному!):

> Гаманець ще з початку своєї появи, призначався для зберігання
>   металевих монет, тому це є його відмінністю до нашого часу. Що
>   стосується портмоне, то його використовують в основному для зберігання
>   паперових грошей, має місце для візитівок, чеків, банківських карт,
>   посвідчення водія.

Отож, як бачимо, все ж таки є суттєва різниця між гаманцем і портмоне.

Comment: Друге Ваше посилання (yakszrobiti.ru) є таким самим рерайтом [російської статті](https://thedifference.ru/chem-otlichaetsya-portmone-ot-koshelka/) на TheDifference.ru, як і останнє посилання (moyaosvita.com.ua) з [відповіді Oksanka S](/a/3748).

Comment: Перше ж Ваше посилання заперечує те, що гаманці є лише жіночими: «Як вибрати модні чоловічі гаманці? <…> І тому модні чоловічі гаманці сьогодні не менш популярні, ніж жіночі» (і [зображення](https://komuchtopodarit.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/mozhno-li-darit-koshelek-3.jpeg) речі, яка згідно з описом не є портмоне через великі розміри й наявність застібки, але виглядає чоловічою).